# Hit the webservice wsdl with the authentication ID and password

Tags: android

getting response from the webservice where authentication ID and password need to be sent for the access of WSDL webservice and also sending xml data to webservice... I knew that the AndroidHttpTransport should be written again according to our needs... so, that we can send in the form as mention below..

httpConnection.call(SoapAction, envelop, xmlData);

unable to mention the right code for AndroidHttpTransport.... Thank's for your concentration..

Answer (score 0):

i dont fully understand but to send any data to server, i use

```
request.addproperty("name",value); //something like this
```

so just add username and password like this and the function on server will get these values as input argument...

Comment: Farhan... try to understand first.. You see all the information and parameter of the xml file in the wsdl file right.. so, if u need to hit the wsdl file with the authentication id and password to access further for hit the method with specified userID and password.. so, how to hit the authentication id and password in the the wsdl file..